# Android API 16 not fitting windows when status bar is shown

Tags: android

Is there any reason why a View is partly hidden (API 16) when the Activity has a status bar?

In this activity, I added a view that has a red border.

[image]

The red border on the bottom should be shown. If I added a bottom margin of 24dp (which is the height of the status bar), the bottom border is shown. Which indicates that the view height isn't properly set.

The code is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    >
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/red_border"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the activity theme is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#0D53CE</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="19" >true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenuStyle</item>
</style>
```

It works when I set:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

But then the status bar isn't there.

This bug only happens in Android 16 that I've tried, in Android >= 21, this doesn't happen.

Thanks :)